# application of kolomogorov's $0-1$ law

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $Y = \lim \sup X_n$ where $X_n$ are all independent bounded random variables.

I am trying to prove that $Y $ is equal to a constant almost surely.

We have, $\{ Y \leq x\}$ is a tail event, so $P(Y \leq x ) = 0$ or $1$, but I am not sure how to conclude $Y$ is constant almost surely, i.e. how does this mean $P(Y = c) = 1$ for a constant $c$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $c=\inf\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{P}(Y\leq x)=1\}$; note that $c$ is a real number because the $X_n$ are bounded.

If $x<c$ then $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq x)<1$, and since $Y$ is measurable with respect to the tail $\sigma$-algebra it follows that $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq x)=0$. Therefore
$$\mathbb{P}(Y<c)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\Big(Y\leq c-\frac{1}{n}\Big)=0 $$

If $x>c$ then $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq x)=1$ by the definition of $c$, hence 
$$ \mathbb{P}(Y\leq c)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\Big(Y\leq c+\frac{1}{n}\Big)=1$$

Finally,
$$ \mathbb{P}(Y=c)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq c)-\mathbb{P}(Y<c)=1-0=1 $$
so $Y$ is constant almost surely.

By the way, this proof works for any tail-measurable random variable.